# Remove empty brackets ( ) from string

Tags: python

I had a problem in removing empty brackets from string, I tried few methods didn't work. kindly help

here is the dataframe

```
data = {'disc': ['( ) -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol methanesulfonate','( ) ( s ) -isopropyl 2 ','( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-phenylbutane ( ) boc-epoxideide']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
```

which have multiple occurrence of `( )` need to remove only empty brackets.

input:

```
      disc
0   ( ) -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol methanesulfonate
1   ( ) ( s ) -isopropyl 2 
2   ( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-p
```

output:

```
     disc
0   -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol methanesulfonate
1   ( s ) -isopropyl 2 
2   ( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-phenylbutane boc-epoxideide
```

using replace is not helping because it will remove all brackets there in the string.

Comment: `.replace("( )", "")`

Comment: Is it always `( )` with single between the brackets? Or could it be more than one space?

Comment: @Aziz always single space

Comment: @naveenkumar as suggested by Bendik in his answer, a simple `replace` will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import re 
You can try using regex module

```
df1["disc"] = df1["disc"].str.replace("\(\\s+\)", "")
```

`\\s+`  means it will detect one or spaces between two brackets

```
 -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol methanesulfonate
 ( s ) -isopropyl 2 
( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-phenylbutane  boc-epoxideide
```

Comment: It would be recommended to use string methods rather than ``apply``, ``df1['disc'].str.replace("\(\s+\)", "")``

Answer (score 1):

replace should work:

```py
a="'( ) -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol"

>>> a.replace("( )","")
>>> "' -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol"
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) does support using regex, so you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'disc': ['( ) -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemethanol methanesulfonate','( ) ( s ) -isopropyl 2 ','( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-phenylbutane ( ) boc-epoxideide']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df1.replace(r'\s*\(\s*\)\s*', '', regex=True)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                                                disc
0  -2,4-dichloro-a- ( chloromethyl ) -benzenemeth...
1                                ( s ) -isopropyl 2
2  ( 2s3s ) -12-epoxy-3- ( boc-amino ) -4-phenylb...
```

Note that you have to inform replace to use regular expression (`regex=True`) and I used so-called raw-string to simplify escaping, `(` and `)` needs to be escaped as they have special meaning in pattern, as for pattern itself I used 0 or more whitespaces (`/s*`) also before and after `(` `)` to also remove leading/trailing ones.